# Inaccurate Digits due to binary representation in BigDecimals. How do I get around it?

Tags: java, bigdecimal

I wanted to write a parser that converts a String to a BigDecimal. 
It is required that it is 100% accurate. (Well, I am currently programming for fun. So I rather ask for it... ;-P)

So I came up with this programm:

```java
public static BigDecimal parse(String term) {
    char[] termArray = term.toCharArray();

    BigDecimal val = new BigDecimal(0D);
    int decimal = 0;
    for(char c:termArray) {
        if(Character.isDigit(c)) {
            if(decimal == 0) {
                val = val.multiply(new BigDecimal(10D));
                val = val.add(new BigDecimal(Character.getNumericValue(c)));
            } else {
                val = val.add(new BigDecimal(Character.getNumericValue(c) * Math.pow(10, -1D * decimal)));
                decimal++;
            }
        }
        if(c == '.') {
            if(decimal != 0) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("There mustn't be multiple points in this number: " + term);
            } else {
                decimal++;
            }
        }
    }

    return val;
}
```

So I tried:

```java
parse("12.45").toString();
```

I expected it to be `12.45`. Instead, it was `12.45000000000000002498001805406602215953171253204345703125`. I know this might be due to limitations of the binary representation. But how can I get around this?

Note: I know that you can just use `new BigDecimal("12.45");`. But that's not my point - I want to write it on my own, regardless of how stupid this might be.

Comment: whenever you see calculation that results in long row of decimal digits - you know there's a double involved. floating point has a hard time in representing decimal values. 
and indeed, `Math.pow()` produces double value. You will need to replace that method call with something else that doesn't involve floating point values

Comment: This is not a parser, and `BigDecimal` already contains constructors and methods that do this correctly.

Comment: @user207421 As I've already mentioned, I'm programming for fun. It is a stupid idea to write this method, as there already exits a constructor in 'BigDecimal' that does this for me. Please read my last sentences.
And I do not understand why this should not be a parser. [See Wikipedia - Parser](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parsing)

Comment: FWIW, I assume you meant `new BigDecimal("12.45")` and not `BigInteger`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's due to the limitations of binary representation.  Any negative power of 10 can't be represented exactly as a `double`.

To get around this, replace all `double` arithmetic with all `BigDecimal` arithmetic.

```
val = val.add(
    new BigDecimal(Character.getNumericValue(c)).divide(BigDecimal.TEN.pow(decimal)));
```

With this I get `12.45`.

Comment: Oh, I see. The inaccuracy "occures" in the calculation of the summand instead of the BigDecimal itself.

Comment: In fact only fractions which are negative powers of 2 can be represented exactly as a double.  Similarly, in decimal, only fractions which exclusively contain powers of 2 and 5 can be represented exactly as a decimal fraction.  Otherwise, the decimal will be repeating.

Comment: Instead of divide(TEN.pow(n)) use movePointLeft(n) or scaleByPowerOfTen(-n), or just BigInteger.valueOf(digit,n)

Answer (score 0):

This can be improved a little. Only divide once. Simply ignore the decimal point inside the loop. Just count the decimals. So `"12.45"` becomes `1245` with `decimal == 2`. Now at the end, you only have to divide that by, in this case, `BigDecimal.TEN.pow(2)` (or 100) to get `12.45`.

```
public static BigDecimal parse(String term) 
{
    char[] termArray = term.toCharArray();

    // numDecimals:  -1: no decimal point at all, so no need to divide
    //                0: decimal point found, but no digits counted yet
    //              > 0: count of digits after decimal point    

    int numDecimals = -1;
    BigDecimal val = new BigDecimal.ZERO;

    for(char c: termArray) 
    {
        if (Character.isDigit(c)) 
        {
            val = val.multiply(BigDecimal.TEN).add(BigDecimal.valueOf(Character.getNumericValue(c)));
            if (numDecimals != -1)
                numDecimals++;
        }
        else if (c == '.') 
        {
            if (numDecimals != -1) 
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("There mustn't be multiple points in this number: " + term);
            else 
                numDecimals = 0;
        }

    }

    if (numDecimals > 0)
        return val.divide(BigDecimal.TEN.pow(numDecimals));
    else
        return val;
}
```

Note that this function does not work for negative values, nor does it recognize scientific notation. For that, using the original string, an index and `charAt(index)` would probably be more ideal than the current loop. But that was not the question.